# The no of Items per row is dynamic based on text length in recyclerview

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview

Required screen like this:
[image]

Hello Team,
I am working on recyclerview. I need to display arrayList of strings(words) in Recyclerview but all words are different in size.

I know the Recycleview displays the no of items per row is fix but we need dynamic based of words length.

For example,
Word is lengthy then it should show word in first row and if second word is able to adjust in first row then add it otherwise show second word in second row and so on.

Please find attached image for reference.

Thanks,
Arthur

Comment: Please suggest me. Your suggestion will help me alot.